# GCP PubSub Permissions for a topic

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a service account that has permission to particular pubsub topic only.

I create a topic:

```
gcloud pubsub topics create mytopic
```

Then create a service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create my-user \
  --display-name "my-user"
```

Then trying to grant this service account permission:

```
gcloud alpha pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding mytopic \
      --member="serviceAccount:my-user@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
      --role='roles/pubsub.editor'
```

Get the service account json file:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create \
  --iam-account "my-user@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  service-account.json
```

Using this service account json credentials I get denied creating a subscription to this topic.

If I give this user permissions to the entire project's pubsub, I am able to create a subscription to this topic but I dont want to give that much permission to this service account.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject \
  --member="serviceAccount:my-user@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role='roles/pubsub.editor'
```

I am trying to use this and it doesnt seem to work: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/pubsub/topics/add-iam-policy-binding

Am I missing something here?  I would have thought that the role binding for this user to the topic would be enough permission?

Answer (score 9):

It turns out there are permissions on the subscription itself also.  You need to give permission to that for the service account to be able to attach to it.

With this command:  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/pubsub/subscriptions/add-iam-policy-binding

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted my 40 mins on this. Tried using `google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding` with `roles/pubsub.admin` and still it didn't work!  Finally I had it working using `google_pubsub_subscription_iam_policy`.

Answer (score 0):

for creating subscriptions, you need

```
pubsub.subscriptions.create on the containing Cloud project and pubsub.topics.attachSubscription on the requested topic
```

as `pubsub.subscriptions.create` is only contained in `roles/
pubsub.editor` (and `...admin`), you might want to create a custom role for not giving away `delete` etc perms on topics and so on

on the requested topic, you can grant `pubsub.subscriber` for granting `attachSubscription`

via https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#tbl_perm